# Changes across repositories in GitHub

Tags: github

I am making a code change that spans multiple repositories hosted on Github. Is there any way to keep track of these changes in one place?
Something like a cross-repository pull request?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do this.

The best you can do is cross-link your Pull Requests together. See the [GitHub help for linking to issues and PRs](//help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/#issues-and-pull-requests). In particular, if you include `Bob/Scripts#24` in your PR description, then that will automatically link to PR #24 in the repo called `Scripts` owned by `Bob`.

As an alternative, you might be able to refactor your changes to preserve backwards compatibility, so that you can submit one PR at a time. E.g., say you are modifying repo `A` and repo `B`, and `A` depends on `B`. First submit a PR for `B` that adds new functionality and marks some methods as deprecated. After it is merged, you can submit your PR for `A` that uses the new methods. Finally, you can submit a PR for `B` that removes the deprecated methods. This is slightly more complicated, but can be a better choice depending on the project, because the third PR can be delayed if there are other projects that use the deprecated methods.